# How do I remove elements from a list in a Flask/jinja2 loop?

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4

I am currently making a `flask` project, where I want to display four `Bootstrap` columns per row in. In order to do that, I thought I could just do like this:

```
my_list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","k",
       "l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
       "v","w","x","y","z"]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for i in my_list[:4]:
        print(i)
        my_list.remove(i)

# returns every element of my_list in order
```

However, when I tried to do this in the actual project, I got an error, no matter where I put

> {% number_of_texts.remove[j] %}: 
>   "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag
>   'number_of_texts'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor'
>   or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'."

These are my variables from main.py:

```
@app.route('/texts')
def texts():
number_of_texts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
return render_template('texts.html', title="All texts", number_of_texts=number_of_texts, len=len(number_of_texts))
```

This is my code from texts.py:

```
{% for i in range(len) %}
<div class="row"> 
    {% for j in number_of_texts[:4] %}
        <div class="col m-1"> 
            <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; height: 28rem; border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px">
                <img src="static\img\p_01.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style="object-fit: cover; border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">row: {{ i }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">column: {{ j }}</p>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('specific_text', text_no=1) }}" class="btn btn-dark">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}{% number_of_texts.remove[j] %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

If I don't remove `j` from the list `number_of_texts`, then apart from getting too many columns of course, I get the layout that I actually want. Here's what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V07oW.jpg

Is there another way I can remove those items from the `list`, so that I only display each element in the list once?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your actual use case is to split things into rows, you'll just want the [`batch` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#batch).

```
{% for row in things|batch(4) %}
  <div class="row">
     {% for item in row if item %}
        <div class="item">
           {{ item }}
        </div>
     {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

See the aforelinked documentation on the `fill_with=` parameter too; the above will simply leave the last row having less items if the length of `things` is not divisible by 4 thanks to the `if item`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're an absolute legend. Works like a charm now :D