# Flask with html

Tags: python, jinja2

i have written this code with flask:

```
<select name="status">
{% set a=stati %}
<option value="{{i[3]}}">{{i[3]}}</option>
{% a.remove(i[3]) %}
{% for c in a %}
    <option value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

I get this error message, how i can fix it?

{% a.remove(i[3]) %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'a'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.

I Try with

```
{{ a.remove(i[3]) }}
```

And with
{% set a.remove(i[3]) %}

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004775/how-do-i-remove-elements-from-a-list-in-a-flask-jinja2-loop

Answer (score 0):

You should not apply CRUD operations inside the template. That's why you use Flask...